# Optimization Strategies for FFT sound transformations using GPGPU

Tags: gpgpu

I want to run audio FFT transformations on a GPU using, possibly, OpenCL.
What are the best optimization strategies for:

- converting audio signals to FFT;
- transfer them to the graphics card;
- compute those
- return the FFT into audio signal domain

if possible, i would like to do such a thing:

- with minimum latency possible;
- in real time;
- using really big fft window sizes;
- using really high sample rates and bit depth